# Azure Key Vault not loading secret values with thumbprint authentication in .NET 7 Web API

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, .net-7.0

I am trying to load values for secrets from Azure Key Vault using thumbprint authentication in my .NET 7 Web API application. I have implemented the following code to configure Azure Key Vault integration:

Configuration Extension method:

```cs
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAppConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        configurationBuilder
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        // For Localhost, we're using appsettings.json file, it will not be overridden when running on Localhost
        if (!hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Localhost"))
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        }
        configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        return configurationBuilder;
    }

    public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(this IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        if (!hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            var builtConfig = configurationBuilder.Build();
            var keyVaultEndpoint = $"https://{builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Name"]}.vault.azure.net/";

            var clientId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:ClientId"];
            var thumbprint = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:Thumbprint"];
            var tenantId = builtConfig["KeyVaultConfigOption:TenantId"];

            var certificate = GetCertificate(thumbprint);

            var clientCertificateCredential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultEndpoint), clientCertificateCredential);
        }
        
        return configurationBuilder;
    }
    
    private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbprint)
    {
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == thumbprint);
        store.Close();

        if (cert == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to find the certificate for thumbprint:{thumbprint}");

        return cert;
    }
}
```

Program.cs file:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{
    // Environment configuration
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    var env = builder.Environment;

    configuration.AddAppConfiguration(env);

    // Add azure key vault configuration
    builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVaultConfiguration(env);

    builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblyContaining<Program>());
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

    builder.Services.AddApplication();
    builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);

    builder.Services.AddHelpers();

    builder.Services.AddControllers()
       // Configures the JSON serialization options for controllers.
       .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        });

    builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    // Authentication & Authorization
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseSwaggerWithVersioning();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //DEV configurations
}

app.Run();
```

appsettings.json file:

```
"ServiceBusConfigOption": {
    "ConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={SecretURL}/)",
    "TopicsEmailTemplate": "EmailTemplates",
    "TopicUserSetting": "UserSettings"
  }
```

But when I debugging my code and check ServiceBusConfigOption.ConnectionString value it still showing with "@Microsoft.KeyVault" and not loaded the actual value from azure key vault secrets.

```cs
public class AzureServiceBusFactory : IMessageBusFactory
{
    private readonly ServiceBusConfigOption _serviceBusConfigOption;

    public AzureServiceBusFactory(IOptions<ServiceBusConfigOption> configurationSettings)
    {
       _serviceBusConfigOption = configurationSettings.Value;
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing in the configuration, or any additional steps required to properly load the values for secrets from Azure Key Vault using thumbprint authentication?

Comment: `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri={SecretURL}/)` works only for Azure App Service.If you want to retrieve the secret from this you need to add the key-value in the App Service Configuration section of the deployed app.

Comment: AFAIK,this won't work locally.

Comment: @Harshitha So, Could you please suggest if there any other alternative way to load specific settings from key vault?

Comment: Please refer this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454780/how-to-access-keyvault-secret-values-from-within-startup-cs-for-serilog-sql-sin).